# Why is my container not center aligned vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is my container not center aligned vertically and horizontally.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <header></header>
  <article></article>
  <aside></aside>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-center: center;
}

.flex-container > * {
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

header {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 1);
}

article {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .8);
}

aside {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .6);
}

footer {
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .4);
}
```

Below is a fiddle for the same.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bAayc

Comment: What have you done to center it?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Have you seen my codepen... it says algin-items and justify-center to center.

Comment: That aligns the contents...you still have to center the container.

Comment: should justify-center: center; not do the job....

Comment: The container is 100% wide and IS centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `justify-content: center` for the horizontal alignment.

For the vertical center alignment you have two possibilities:

1. Declare all parent elements as 100% height. That is the `<body style="height:100%">` *and* the `<html style="height:100%">`. Otherwise it is just 100% of the parent element, which has just the required size to fit all content.
2. Make the position of the flex-container `fixed` or `absolute`:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: why do we need to vie height and width of parents 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't declare it. Add following to your element:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-center: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Keep in mind that the `transform` attribute will not work in IE8. To achieve this you need to add negative `margin` in IE8 instead of `translate`.

IE8 fallback:

```
.flex-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -(HEIGHT-OF-ELEMENT);
  margin-left: -(WIDTH-OF-ELEMENT);
}
```

For that you need to know the `width` and `height`of your `.flex-container`.

**Edit:**

*Okay I got an downvote for my `position: absolute;` solution. Instead of downvoting an possible and correct solution, fellow users, just improve my answer. Thanks.*

You can also add `margin: auto;` to your `.flex-container` but then you need to set a fixed `width`. This will make your element horizontally centered. But not vertically. For that you still need to apply `position: absolute;` or `position: relative;`.

Comment: Absolute position? Really? He could just center it with margin auto.

Comment: @Paulie_D true but for margin auto, OP has to set width of `flex-container` also.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. He wants it horizontally and vertically centered. `margin: auto;` will only work for the horizontal center.